# Laravel/Eloquent whereHasAll solution?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

So if I have models

Song

and

Writer

and Song has many Writers

And I want to query songs such that I only get songs where all its writers have a certain field that is true, what would my solution be?

The Laravel whereHas function will get all songs that have at least one writer with that field, like so.

```
Song::whereHas('writers', function($query){
    $query->where('writerField', '=', true);
});
```

But what is the pure eloquent way to make sure **EVERY** writer related to a Song has that 'writerField' set to true?

Comment: plz. add Your models code to Your question, and also describe how they have relations (field names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the count feature and invert the query.

```
Song::whereHas('writers', function($query){
    $query->whereNull('writerField');
}, '=', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

My realization is like this:

**songs** table has: **id**, **title** and etc
**writers** table has: **id**, **name** and etc
**writers_songs** table has: **writer_id**, **song_id**

```
class Song extends Model {
    protected $table = 'songs';

    public final function writers() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Writer', 'WriterSong');
    }
}

class WriterSong extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'writers_songs'; // it has to fields: song_id, writer_id
}

class Writer extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'writers';

    public final function songs() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Song', 'WriterSong');
    }
}
```

and this is how I do request:

```
$Songs = Song::with('writers')->whereHas('writers')->where('title', 'like', '%hello%')->get();
foreach($Songs AS $Song) {
    $Writers = $Song->writers;
    echo "Title: ".$Song->title.'<br/>';
    foreach($Writers AS $Writer) {
       echo "Writer: ".$Writer->name.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

it's simple way than keeping additional field in songs table

Comment: Appreciate the answer number. I will def take this info consideration. The solution I found is working great for me.

Comment: nice to know You've found answer, but when You'll need to make many to many realization You'll have to do like mine. Cuz song may have many writers, and writer also can have many songs, so that's the best way to make relation, it's flexible.

Comment: In my system right now writers are unique and cannot belong to many songs. I should have clarified that from the onset. But thank you so much for the time you took to post.

Comment: I've read it :)  just left my realization, maybe it will be helpful to many developers that will come to this post in search of many-to-many and hasManyThrough.

Answer (score -2):

I think the whereHas makes a inner join, in this case Songs with Writers so since that is the intersection between those 2 tables you are actually getting the result you are asking for. This [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-eloquent-wherehas-function) explains a bit of what I said.

Comment: so this is more of a comment than an answer. You could try to answer it by casting some sql for him rather than pointing to an outside resource.